# Rating Feature not disabling on SPO Pages - SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, csom, jsom, rating

I have a requirement where Admin will have the ability to turn `ON/OFF` the `rating feature for SPO Pages` and the UI Control should be able to `display/hide` based on the setting.

Steps for turning ON the Rating feature:

- Document Library Settings -> Rating Settings -> Enable
- Adding the below tag to the page layout.

  SharePointPortalControls:AverageRatingFieldControl id="PageRatingControl" FieldName="Rating (0-5)" runat="server" />

By doing so, I'm able to see the Rating control on the page but I'm not able to hide it even after disabling the Rating setting.

Am I doing something wrong? I'm thinking of a JSOM way of solving this.
Any suggestions are highly appreciated :)

Comment: I'm not sure why I couldn't paste the exact SharePoint tag. I have made it visible, only by removing the **<** tag from the front.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the Rating control, we can using the following CSS style to achieve it.

```
<style>
#RatingsCtrl_ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_PageRatingControl{
    display:none;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I would need to access the rating setting value if it is enabled/disabled in the javascript so that I would apply a CSS fix to make it display/hide. So, I'm looking for a way to access the Rating Setting in Javascript.

Comment: It is not an API can access the Rating Setting in JavaScript code.